# How to make a tiled color background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, print-design, background

[image: sample design I want to recreate]

How can I create that type of solid tiled color background... should I use Illustrator for this or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use Illustrator's "Object Mosaic" function.

1. Create your gradient.

[image]

2. The mosaic function only works on raster images so first select your gradient object and rasterize (*Object → Rasterize...*)

   Then run the mosaic function (*Object → Create Object Mosaic...*)

[image]

3. You can add a drop shadow effect (*Effect → Stylize → Drop Shadow...*) to specific tiles by selecting them with the Direct Selection Tool (you may need to bring them forward too; right-click "Arrange → Bring to Front").

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

There’s probably lots of ways to build that, in many different tools. Here’s a quick way to do it in Photoshop.

1. Draw a gradient. Note that I’ve created the gradient on a 45º angle (we’ll rotate it back later).

[image: Photoshop draw a gradient]

2. Apply a mosaic filter, using `Filter` → `Pixelate` → `Mosaic`.

[image: Photoshop mosaic filter]

3. Rotate the layer by 45º. (I’ve also turned it into a smart object, which isn't essential, but it will let you rotate and resize the layer without cumulative quality loss).

[image: Photoshop smart object]

4. If you want the shadow effect, it can be added via another shape layer on top, with a shadow layer style, and the fill set to 0% opacity (just the fill, not the entire layer).

[image: Photoshop shadow effect]